# Configure Tomcat web app session together with a physical load balancer

Tags: tomcat, load-balancing

I need to set up a web application on Tomcat. In front of the web application, I have a physical load balancer (Kemp LoadMaster 3000).

If I set the session time to 60 minutes through the website's web.xml:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Should I set the session timeout to 60 minutes in the load balancer? Or some other values?

Answer (score 0):

I did research and believe the answer is YES.

Here is the link: https://support.kemptechnologies.com/hc/en-us/articles/204373265-KEMP-LoadMaster

```
In general, matching this value to your server timeout value is recommended.
```

If someone feels there is a better way, please let me know!